# Get something that's three minutes older then the last date modified

Tags: php, date, comparison

I have the following:

```
$isOlderThenThreeMinutes = $this->getDateModified() <= strtotime('-3 minutes');
```

pretty basic. How ever I was logging this the whole time and I get `1` every time this check returns. So I thought ok what happens if I wait 15 minutes and check it again, still `1` thus its never truly older then three minutes.

Whats wrong with this? `getDateModified()` returns `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

How do I say: *if older then 3 minutes return true, else return false*? it returns one every time, even if its 2 seconds old or 30 minutes old ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `$this->getDateModified()` to a Unix Timestamp since that is what `strtotime(-3 minutes)` returns.

```
isOlderThenThreeMinutes = strtotime($this->getDateModified()) <= strtotime('-3 minutes');
```

Comment: When the code with this is run and the variable is logged I still see `1` is this normal? what's this mean? Because 2 seconds does not mean true .... T hats not older then 3 minutes.

Comment: Yes, the `1` means true. Try putting some sample values in place of `$this->getDateModified()` and see what happens.

Comment: but the date last modified was, and I can verify this, 2 seconds ago - so how is 2 seconds older then 3 minutes? It should be false

Comment: So why is it returning true?

Comment: Check to make sure you are getting expected values from `$this->getDateModified()` as in the example I posted it does not return true

Answer (score 1):

[`strtotime()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns a timestamp, so you would need:

```
$isOlderThenThreeMinutes =  strtotime($this->getDateModified()) <= strtotime('-3 minutes');
```